# lapply on several subsets of data frame

Tags: r, lapply

I have a dataframe `data` containing the `chromosome` and `position` of mutated nucleotides within a genome:

```
structure(list(chrom = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), pos = c(10L, 200L, 134L, 400L, 600L, 1000L, 
20L, 33L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 100L, 123L)), .Names = c("chrom", 
"pos"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

---

```
  chrom  pos
1     1   10
2     1  200
3     1  134
4     1  400
5     1  600
6     1 1000
```

And another `tss_locations`, containing the location of a feature (`tss`) within a `gene` and the `chromosome` it's on:

```
structure(list(gene = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("gene1", "gene10", "gene11", "gene2", 
"gene3", "gene4", "gene5", "gene6", "gene7", "gene8", "gene9"
), class = "factor"), chrom = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L), tss = c(5L, 10L, 23L, 1340L, 313L, 88L, 44L, 57L, 
88L, 74L, 127L)), .Names = c("gene", "chrom", "tss"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

---

```
   gene chrom  tss
1 gene1     1    5
2 gene2     1   10
3 gene3     1   23
4 gene4     2 1340
5 gene5     2  313
6 gene6     2   88
```

I'm trying to calculate the distance to the closest `tss` **on the same chromosome** for each `pos` in `data`.

So far, I can calculate the distance from each `data$pos` to **any** `tss_locations$tss` (i.e. the closest `tss` to each `pos` irrespective of chromosome):

```
fun <- function(p) {
  # Get index of nearest tss
  index<-which.min(abs(tss_locations$tss - p))
  # Lookup the value
  closestTss<-tss_locations$tss[[index]]
  # Calculate the distance
  dist<-(closestTss-p)
  list(snp=p, closest=closestTss, distance2nearest=dist)
}

# Run function for each 'pos' in data
dist2tss<-lapply(data$pos, fun)

# Convert to data frame and sort descending:
dist2tss<-do.call(rbind, dist2tss)
dist2tss<-as.data.frame(dist2tss)

dist2tss<-arrange(dist2tss,(as.numeric(distance2nearest)))
dist2tss$distance2nearest<-as.numeric(dist2tss$distance2nearest)
```

---

```
head(dist2tss)

  snp closest distance2nearest
1 600     313             -287
2 400     313              -87
3 200     127              -73
4 100      88              -12
5  33      23              -10
6 134     127               -7
```

However, I would like to be able to find the closest `tss` **on the same chromosome** for each `pos`.

I know that I could apply this to each chromosome individually, but I want to see the global distances (across all chromosomes), but only make comparisons between `pos`itions and `tss`s on the same chromosome.

How can I adjust this to achieve this goal? Subset both data frames by chromosome and merge the results?

Is this the right approach so far?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work to get the closest tss for each chromosome in the `data` dataframe.

```
data <- structure(list(chrom = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), pos = c(10L, 200L, 134L, 400L, 600L, 1000L, 
                                                              20L, 33L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 100L, 123L)), .Names = c("chrom", 
                                                                                                                     "pos"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))

tss_locations <- structure(list(gene = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
                                                  10L, 11L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("gene1", "gene10", "gene11", "gene2", 
                                                                                "gene3", "gene4", "gene5", "gene6", "gene7", "gene8", "gene9"
                                                  ), class = "factor"), chrom = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                  3L, 4L, 4L), tss = c(5L, 10L, 23L, 1340L, 313L, 88L, 44L, 57L, 
                                                                                                       88L, 74L, 127L)), .Names = c("gene", "chrom", "tss"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 -11L))

# Generate needed values by applying function to all rows and transposing t() the results
data[,c("closest_gene", "closest_tss", "min_dist")] <- t(apply(data, 1, function(x){
   # Get subset of tss_locations where the chromosome matches the current row
   genes <- tss_locations[tss_locations$chrom == x["chrom"], ]

   # Find the minimum distance from the current row's pos to the nearest tss location
   min.dist <- min(abs(genes$tss - x["pos"]))

   # Find the closest tss location to the current row's pos
   closest_tss <- genes[which.min(abs(genes$tss - x["pos"])), "tss"]

   # Check if closest tss location is less than pos and set min.dist to negative if true
   min.dist <- ifelse(closest_tss < x["pos"], min.dist * -1, min.dist)

   # Find the closest gene to the current row's pos
   closest_gene <- as.character(genes[which.min(abs(genes$tss - x["pos"])), "gene"])

   # Return the values to the matrix
   return(c(closest_gene, closest_tss, min.dist))
}))
```

Comment: Thanks - seems close but the output is slightly off. E.g. On running it the first row of `data` looks like: `1      1   10        gene1           5        0` - where the closest `tss` is `5`, but the `min_dist` is `0`

Comment: You're right, I've edited the answer to correct that.

Comment: Great! The data I provided in the question was toy data. My real data is the same, except `data` has a few extra columns.  How can I adjust this to accommodate for that (and explicitly select the `pos` column)?

Comment: Additional columns in `data` won't affect the function at all. The code is already explicitly checking the `chrom` and `pos` columns (IE `x["chrom"]` and `x["pos"]`)

Comment: Would you be able to add a few lines of explanation to your answer?  I don't want the absolute distance from the `tss`, but when I change `min.dist <- min(abs(genes$tss - x["pos"]))` to `min.dist <- min(genes$tss - x["pos"])` the  `min.dist` values are wrong for negative distances, but correct for positive distances - why is this?

Comment: That would happen because you are then introducing negative numbers into the min function. For instance if there if `pos = 5` and it is choosing between `tss = 1` or `tss = 6`, using `abs` gives `abs(1-5) = 4` and `abs(6-5) = 1` since 1 is the min, tss 6 is chosen. Without using `abs` we get `1-5 = -4` and `6-5 = 1`, in this case -4 is the min, so tss 1 is chosen. If you want to show negative values for the distance if the tss is less than the pos, that can be accomplished with an `ifelse` check, and then multiply the `min.dist` value by -1 when appropriate.