# Merge data frames in for loop

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I have two data frames `data`:

```
data <- structure(list(chrom = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), pos = c(10L, 200L, 134L, 400L, 600L, 1000L, 
20L, 33L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 100L, 123L)), .Names = c("chrom", 
"pos"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

And `tss_locations`:

```
tss_locations <- structure(list(gene = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("gene1", "gene10", "gene11", "gene2", 
"gene3", "gene4", "gene5", "gene6", "gene7", "gene8", "gene9"
), class = "factor"), chrom = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L), tss = c(5L, 10L, 23L, 1340L, 313L, 88L, 44L, 57L, 
88L, 74L, 127L)), .Names = c("gene", "chrom", "tss"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

And a function to find the closest match between a position in `data` (`pos`) and a position in `tss_locations` (`tss`). [I would like to make comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489913/lapply-on-several-subsets-of-data-frame/45490972?noredirect=1#comment77974044_45490972) only where the `chrom` value is the same for both `pos` and `tss`.

So far, I am achiving this by first filtering both data frames to select the same chrom, and then running them through my function:

```
# Filter both data frames on same chrom
data<-filter(data, chrom == 1)
tss_locations<-filter(tss_locations, chrom == 1)
```

---

```
# apply fun2
dist2tss<-lapply(data$pos, fun2)
```

---

```
fun2 <- function(p) {
  # Get index of nearest tss
  index<-which.min(abs(tss_locations$tss - p))
  # Get corresponding tss, chrom and gene
  closestTss<-tss_locations$tss[index]
  chrom<-as.character(tss_locations$chrom[index])
  gene<-as.character(tss_locations$gene[index])

  # Calculate distance 
  dist<-(p-closestTss)
  list(p, closestTss, dist, chrom, gene)
}
```

---

```
# Convert to data frame
dist2tss<-do.call(rbind, dist2tss)
dist2tss<-as.data.frame(dist2tss)
colnames(dist2tss)=c("snp", "closest_tss", "min_dist", "chrom", "closest_gene")
dist2tss$min_dist<-as.numeric(dist2tss$min_dist)
```

I've tried putting this in a for loop, i.e.:

```
for (c in levels(data$chrom)){

  data<-filter(data, chrom == c)
  tss_locations<-filter(tss_locations, chrom == c)
  ...
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get this to return a data frame for each chromosome, and then merge them together, so that I can plot the global distances.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bit of a toy example but build a list in the loop and do.call at the end (presuming they all have the same column structure?)

```
df1 <- data.frame(cell=c(1,2,3),val=c(345,123,466))
df2 <- data.frame(cell=c(67,3,2),val=c(234,234,56))
df3 <- data.frame(cell=c(3,67,23),val=c(23,8,34))

l <- list()

for(i in 1:3){
  df.now <- get(paste0("df",i))
  l[[i]] <- df.now
}

do.call(rbind,l)
```

in the context of yours, you build the dataframe for each chromosome as you did in the initial workflow and at the end of the loop, populate the list element with that new dataframe. Then do.call them altogether, something like this:

```
l <- list()

for (c in levels(data$chrom)){
  data<-filter(data, chrom == c)
  tss_locations<-filter(tss_locations, chrom == c)
  dist2tss<-lapply(df$pos, fun2)
  dist2tss<-do.call(rbind, dist2tss)
  dist2tss<-as.data.frame(dist2tss)

  colnames(dist2tss)=c("snp", "closest_tss", "min_dist", "chrom", "closest_gene")
  dist2tss$min_dist<-as.numeric(dist2tss$min_dist)
  l[[c]] <- dist2tss
}
dist2tss<-do.call(rbind,l)
```

Comment: But what if my `chrom`s have names like `2R` and `X`?

Comment: same principle, you just loop through the names, generate the list (each list element is now called the same as 'chrom') and do.call. The row.names in the resulting data frame will be that of the chrom it belongs to.

Comment: Like this `... l[[c]] <- dist2tss }` `do.call(rbind,l)` ?

Comment: yeah, that should do it